# Reading QR code from a webpage using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, selenium-webdriver, qr-code

I am trying to build a bot that can read qr code from any website so I chose whatsapp web. I tried the online method of reading qr code which is I have mentioned below but did not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import cv2
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

time.sleep(5)
cv2.QRCodeDetector(driver)
```

I started by writing only this much code first but i am getting this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\practice.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.QRCodeDetector(driver)
SystemError: <class 'cv2.QRCodeDetector'> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Befor this code I was trying this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from qrcode import QRCode
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
QRCode(driver)
```

Comment: did you look a the documentation? if not go and look at it, besides what are you going to do with we.whatsapp qr code?

Comment: i initially thought about automating whastsapp with this qr scanner.

Comment: getting the qr code image from whatsapp is not as simple as two lines.
before using qr, try to make sure you get the image first (try to display it or save it somewhere). better try with simpler websites first.